# Open Android App from Dialer

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver

I have implemented a Broadcast Receiver to open my app from the launcher. The number to open is *#1234#*

Now it works perfectly in some devices while it doesn't in some. Now my question is how is this even possible?

If it works, then it should work in all devices isn't it? Also I need suggestions on what would be the best practice to ensure that it works on all devices.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

**Now my question is how is this even possible?**

Yes it is pretty much possible.

**If it works, then it should work in all devices isn't it?**

No, Reason behind your implementation not working can be but not **limited to** are given below.

1) Every Phone Manufacturer tweak Android OS code(As Android is Open Source). There can be chance of have given priority to System Apps first then public 
apps.

2) There can be other apps(System/Public both) running on the phone, which are listening on the same BroadCast Intent and taking action before your app does anything.

3) Phone are slow and your receiver getting command little later then expected!!

Share more details on your testing to get more feedback.

Comment: I see. What I have observed that, it doesn't work if I use "*#1234#*" but works if I use "1234" only. Can this be a reason, I mean the star and the hash?

Comment: It can be, like I said, some manufacturer can add a check, where they do not send broadcast messages for this type of number which has Star and Hash.

Comment: So is the best way to do is using only the number?